# Number of distinct Relations

Tags: combinatorics, functions, relations

Suppose X has n elements and Y has m elements. What is the number of distinct relations that could be drawn from X into Y?

Comment: What are your thoughts?

Comment: No of ordered pairs (x,y) = mn
So, number of distinct relations would be equal to number of elements in Power set (excluding null set) = 2^mn - 1

Answer (score 0):

How many ordered pairs are in XxY?
If S has k elements, how many subsets of S are there?

BTW, the answers are the same when X, Y and S are infinite.

Comment: No of ordered pairs (x,y) = mn So, number of distinct relations would be equal to number of elements in Power set (excluding null set) = 2^mn - 1
Am I correct?

Comment: @AkashMalhotra  Almost correct.  Is not the empty set a relation?

Comment: Yes, it'll be 2^mn then